# Using AynscSpinner to process callbacks from two subscribers

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback, ros

I looked at [AsyncSpinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497670/multithreading-behaviour-with-ros-asyncspinner) and want to check if my understanding is correct. Given two callbacks `cb1` registered to one subscriber `sub1` and `cb2` registered to another different subscriber `sub2` , the frequency of subscribing to message in sub1 is much higher than that in `sub2` . We may have a global callback queue like `[cb1, cb1, cb1, cb1, cb2, cb1, cb1, cb1, cb1]` . Also, the processing time of `cb1` is very long. Does the process still get stuck even if we use AsyncSpinner because ROS prevents a callback registered in one subscriber from being called simultaneously by multiple threads by default. For example, we have 4 threads but 3 threads are idle and waiting for 1 thread to finish execution of `cb1` since the next callback available for other threads is still `cb1`. Thus, the process is still stuck and behaves like single threaded spinning because other threads have to wait while one thread is processing `cb1`. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48544551/5235574):

> An async spinner tries to [call](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/1e67842d7624205d94ed697c830c455d3f099db1/clients/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp#L393) available callbacks in the
> callback queue as fast as the rate allows. If the callback is already
> in process (by an other thread) the `CallResult` is `TryAgain`. This
> means a new attempt will be started later on.