# ROS1 Callback Threads Behavior: Two Callback Accessing Shared Data

Tags: c++, ros

My question is that is the callback thread-safe? For multiple callbacks that may access and potentially modify shared data, is adding mutex locks a good practice?

I am testing the behavior of running two threads with two callback functions that access and modify shared data.

I have found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497670/multithreading-behaviour-with-ros-asyncspinner), but in my simple experiments, I am expecting something such as race condition happening, but it did not happen.

I wrote a publisher node which can publish two `String` messages in two threads and each message will be pubished for one second with different frequency.

```cpp
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "AB_topic_pub");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::Publisher pub_a = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("msg_a", 200);
  ros::Publisher pub_b = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("msg_b", 200);

  int COUNT_A = 0, COUNT_B = 0;

  ros::Duration(2.0).sleep();

  boost::thread pub_thread_a(
    [&]()
    {
      ROS_INFO("Publishing A for one second.");
      ros::Time start_time = ros::Time::now();
      ros::Rate freq(1000);
      while (ros::Time::now() - start_time < ros::Duration(1.0)) {
        std_msgs::String MSG_A;
        MSG_A.data = "A" + std::to_string(COUNT_A);
        pub_a.publish(MSG_A);
        freq.sleep();
        COUNT_A++;
      }
    }
  );
  boost::thread pub_thread_b(
    [&]()
    {
      ROS_INFO("Publishing B for one second.");
      ros::Time start_time = ros::Time::now();
      ros::Rate freq(200);
      while (ros::Time::now() - start_time < ros::Duration(1.0)) {
        std_msgs::String MSG_B;
        MSG_B.data = "B" + std::to_string(COUNT_B);
        pub_b.publish(MSG_B);
        freq.sleep();
        COUNT_B++;
      }
    }
  );

  pub_thread_a.join();
  pub_thread_b.join();

  std::cout << "A COUNT: " << COUNT_A << std::endl;
  std::cout << "B COUNT: " << COUNT_B << std::endl;
}
```

I wrote a subscriber node with two callback queues. In the following code, I want to count the how many times the callbacks are called in total. I defined two variables `COUNT_WO_LOCK` without mutex guarding and `COUNT_W_LOCK` with a mutex guarding.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "callback_lock_test");

  ros::NodeHandle nh_a;
  ros::NodeHandle nh_b;

  ros::CallbackQueue cq_a, cq_b;

  nh_a.setCallbackQueue(&cq_a);
  nh_b.setCallbackQueue(&cq_b);

  int COUNT_WO_LOCK;
  COUNT_WO_LOCK = 0;
  int COUNT_W_LOCK;
  COUNT_W_LOCK = 0;
  boost::mutex LOCK;

  boost::function<void(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg)> cb_a = 
      [&](const std_msgs::StringConstPtr &msg)
      {
        LOCK.lock();
        COUNT_W_LOCK++;
        LOCK.unlock();
        COUNT_WO_LOCK++;

        ROS_INFO("[Thread ID: %s] I am A, heard: [%s]", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(boost::this_thread::get_id()).c_str() , msg->data.c_str());
      };
  boost::function<void(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg)> cb_b = 
      [&](const std_msgs::StringConstPtr &msg)
      {
        LOCK.lock();
        COUNT_W_LOCK++;
        LOCK.unlock();
        COUNT_WO_LOCK++;

        ROS_WARN("\t\t[Thread ID: %s] I am B, heard: [%s]", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(boost::this_thread::get_id()).c_str() , msg->data.c_str());
      };

  

  // A pub for one second at 1000Hz
  ros::Subscriber sub_a = nh_a.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("msg_a", 200, 
      cb_a, ros::VoidConstPtr(), ros::TransportHints().tcpNoDelay(true));
  // B pub for one second at 200Hz
  ros::Subscriber sub_b = nh_b.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("msg_b", 200, 
      cb_b, ros::VoidConstPtr(), ros::TransportHints().tcpNoDelay(true));
  
  boost::thread spin_thread_a(
      [&]()
      {
        ROS_ERROR("\t\t\t\t\t [Spinner Thead ID: %s]", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(boost::this_thread::get_id()).c_str());
        while (!sub_a.getNumPublishers()) { }
        while (ros::ok())
          cq_a.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration());
      }
  );
  boost::thread spin_thread_b(
      [&]()
      {
        ROS_ERROR("\t\t\t\t\t [Spinner Thead ID: %s]", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(boost::this_thread::get_id()).c_str());
        while (!sub_b.getNumPublishers()) { }
        while (ros::ok())
          cq_b.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration());
      }
  );

  spin_thread_a.join();
  spin_thread_b.join();

  if (ros::isShuttingDown()) {
    std::cout << "LOCKED COUNT: " << COUNT_W_LOCK << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UNLOCKED COUNT: " << COUNT_WO_LOCK << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I first launched the subscriber node and then launched the publisher node. I am expecting that `COUNT_W_LOCK` is `1200` and `COUNT_WO_LOCK` is `<1200`, but in fact they are all `1200`.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497670/multithreading-behaviour-with-ros-asyncspinner/48544551#48544551

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I've read that answer. The question here is that I have two callback queues.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment *callbacks* are thread safe in ROS. I think the issue is what you're describing vs what you're expecting might be a little different. The short answer is that for a single callback, even if you have multiple messages published at once, there will only every be one execution of that callback at a given time; i.e. 2 threads will not execute that callback at the same time. This is because on the backend ROS subscribers use a queue. So as callbacks are executed the last message is popped off the queue.

Do note that there are potential thread safety issues with *accessing* that data before the threads return. It's not something your code does, but issues can pop up if your main thread is editing or accessing data at the same time as the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand one callback can only be executed by one thread at a time. However, I have **TWO** callback queues for `msg_a` and `msg_b` respectively. Indeed, for each callback, there is only one thread spinning and no multi-spinner. I'm assuming that `spin_thread_a` and `spin_thread_b` can run simultaneously so that there can have race conditions.

Comment: Ah, sorry, read that quickly while eating lunch. Yes, for two callback queues the thread safety will still stand. In practice each thread will be querying it's own queue, so still no issue there.